# Last.fm get charts by date

Tags: last.fm

I want to get charts at a specific date.

The API page only has current charts: http://www.last.fm/api/show/chart.getTopTracks

The chart page lets users choose a date: http://www.last.fm/charts
So it should be possible but I don't see it in the API.

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: Have you found anything? I have the same problem – all-time charts is not very interesting info :(